# how to select both true and false column value in mysql

Tags: mysql, where-in

I'm having a table called file_download.
I need to display

1. downloaded file list - 
          `select * from file_download where downloaded = 1;`
2. not downloaded file list -
          `select * from file_download where downloaded = 0;`
3. all file list - 
          for all file list, what kind of condition has to mention?

below is the sample table.

> ```
> +----+----------+---------+------------+
> | pk | filename |  file   | downloaded |
> +----+----------+---------+------------+
> |  1 | aaa.txt  | aaa.txt |          1 |
> |  2 | bbb.txt  | aaa.txt |          1 |
> |  3 | ccc.txt  | aaa.txt |          0 |
> |  4 | ccc.txt  | aaa.txt |          1 |
> |  5 | ccc.txt  | aaa.txt |          0 |
> |  6 | ccc.txt  | aaa.txt |          0 |
> +----+----------+---------+------------+
> ```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Um, if `downloaded` can only be 0 or 1, then just don't use `where` criteria.  If it could contain another value, use `in` -- `where downloaded in (0,1)`...

Comment: @seddes, without IN, can we have any other options?

Comment: `WHERE downloaded IN (0,1)` is the most concise way. You can also use `WHERE downloaded = 0 OR downloaded = 1`, but that's unnecessarily long. However, if downloaded has only two possible values there is no reason to use `WHERE` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to do the same

Using OR (cheaper in cost)

> select * from file_download where downloaded = 1 or downloaded = 0

Using IN (short and accurate way)

> select * from file_download where downloaded in (0, 1);

Using is not null (way not recommended)

> select * from file_download where downloaded is not null

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses...
I have done it with

select * from file_download where downloaded <> ?

**?** - for random input value (0, 1)